# Category of sheaves generated by a subcategory?

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

Let $C$ be a category and $D$ a full subcategory of $[C^{op}, \mathrm{Set}]$. Can we form something like *Grothendieck topos generated by* $D$? By that I mean some full subcategory $\mathcal{E}$ of $[C^{op},\mathrm{Set}]$ which is a Grothendieck topos containing $D$ and is somewhat *universal* among those Grothendick topoi (for example, every fully faithful embedding of $D$ into a Grothendieck topos factors through $\mathcal{E}$ or something similar).

Comment: Well, you can certainly take the intersection of all subtoposes of $[C^{\mathrm{op}},\mathrm{Set}]$ containing $D$, but this has no reason to be universal (except in the definitional sense, among subtoposes containing $D$), any more than the closure of some subspace $X$ of a compact space is guaranteed to have a universal property for maps from $X$ into compacts.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Thanks. Okay, this might be sufficient kind of answer for me -- but I don't see any straightforward reason why an intersection of toposes is again a topos. Can you please say something about that?

Comment: One simple argument is that the union of coverages on $C$ remains a coverage, and a bigger coverage corresponds to a smaller topos of sheaves.

Comment: Oh, that's right! Thanks, I guess that's all I wanted to know.